# PHP Object constant runtime Maximum function nesting level

Tags: php, runtime, nested

I'm reaching the maximum function nesting level (full list at the end of question). I realize that the solution to this is `xdebug.max_nesting_level`, but what are the detriments to that? Also, how can I better implement my code.

I'm writing an irc client that right now calls itself a lot.

## Call Stack (folded)

```
#     |    Time        |    Memory     |    Function           |    Location
1     |    0.0010      |    800152     |    {main}( )          |    ..\index.php:0
2     |    0.0010      |    802416     |    IRCBot->__construc |    ..\index.php:225
3     |    0.1104      |    804368     |    IRCBot->cont( )    |    ..\index.php:34
4     |    0.1945      |    814592     |    IRCBot->cont( )    |    ..\index.php:144
......|................|...............|.......................|.....................
96    |    113.8191    |    1121560    |    IRCBot->cont( )    |    ..\index.php:144
97    |    114.0116    |    1126928    |    IRCBot->cont( )    |    ..\index.php:144
98    |    114.2020    |    1132384    |    out( )             |    ..\index.php:105
99    |    114.2020    |    1132384    |    flush2( )          |    ..\index.php:14
```

I know I can solve this by increasing the `max_nesting_level`, but then what happens when the nesting level gets to the new max? Also, is the way that I'm doing this bad for memory etc.

```
function cont($config) {
    $data = fgets($this->socket, 256);
    $this->cont($config);
}
```

## Questions:

> Is increasing the `max_nesting_level` going to increase load on my server?
>
> Is there any way to re-engineer this code to avoid this issue?
>
> Is it bad to run PHP scripts like this on a CGI installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure a while loop would be more efficient. And I also believe you actually want to store all the date that comes back from the socket and not overwrite the contents of $data each time. Additionally it seems not useful to pass the $config variable here. Here an updated version:

```
function cont() {
    while (!feof($this->socket)) {
        fgets($this->socket, 256);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no need to save the data.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is expensive from both a memory and computation standpoint, and if you're already going past 100 calls, that should alert you to the fact that this is not the right application of a recursive call.

For getting data from a socket it absolutely is not a problem that should be solved using recursion.

Comment: The recursion is to capture the messages and such, what would you suggest?